# joining two tables when there's a one to many relationship in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, yii

How can I join two tables if one has one to many relationship?
So I have a product table and a percentage table. 
Product would have  `'percentage ' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Percentage ', 'product_id'),`
So Percentage would be  `'product' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Product', 'product_id'),`

Few things I did:
in gridview, use product as the dataprovider, but the problem there will be an array.
I have tried `$data->percentage[]->percent` it didn't return anything.

i've also tried to use the percentage table as the dataprovider, sure, it shows the data but it doesn't show the entire product list.

I've also tried joining the tables, product model: (also tried the reverse for the other table)

```
public function getPercentage()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = 'product_id';
    $criteria->with = array('percentage'=>array('select'=>'percent'));
    return new  CActiveDataProvider($this,
            array('criteria' => $criteria));
}
```

essentially, I'm looking for the entire product list with the corresponding percentage.

Comment: do you want to show all Percentage in a column?

Comment: no, in percentage the criteria has between dates, thus it should really return one but because of the relationship, it's still going to be one to many.